# Doctrine ORM Conditional Association

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, relation

i'm building a Q&A site and my questions, answers and comments are on the same `posts` table. But their `postType` is different. I can get answers for a question and comments for an answer with this association:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Cms\Entity\Post", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $answers;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Cms\Entity\Post", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $comments;
```

But i think this is not the correct way to do this because if i fetch a question both answers and comments are filling with just answers. I have to set a condition for relation like `postType = 1`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your schema is invalid. You schould have two different objects for answers and comments as they are two different things, even if they share a common interface.

You should create two entities, `Answer` and `Comment` and create assocations to them. As they are almost the same thing you could create an abstract class, `AbstractContent`, that defines all required fields and accessor methods. Doctrine supports inheritance so the final database schema will be exactly the same, but your OO model will be correct.

```
/** 
 * @MappedSuperclass 
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(type = "string", name = "discriminator")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({ "answer" = "Answer", "comment" = "Comment" })
 */
abstract class AbstractContent {
    /** @Column(type = "integer") @Id @GeneratedValue("AUTO") */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="text") */
    protected $content;

    /** @Column(type = "datetime", name = "created_at") */
    protected $createdAt;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Answer extends AbstractContent { }

/** @Entity */
class Comment extends AbstractContent { }
```

---

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Cms\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $answers;

/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Cms\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $comments;
```

You can read more about inheritance in Doctrine on its documentation pages: [Inheritance Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Comment: You are missing "@Entity" or "@ORM\Entity" annotation in your super class. Other than that, the answer is good.

Comment: @Siwei `AbstractContent` by itself isn't an entity so there shouldn't be `@Entity` annotation. Take a look at examples from [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) ;-)

Comment: Maybe it is a doctrine version problem, but in the latest Doctrine 2 ORM (till today 20/Dec/2014), the <code>@Entity</code> tag needs to be included into super class or it will report error "Its not supported to define inheritance information on a mapped superclass".

Answer (score 4):

Use Doctrine's [Filtering Collections Criteria class](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). You can even filter the collection first before the sql query:

> If the collection has not been loaded from the database yet, the
>   filtering API can work on the SQL level to make optimized access to
>   large collections.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

...

    /** @var Collection */
    protected $posts;

    /**
     * @return Post[]
     */
    public function getAnswers()
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('postType', 'answer'))
        ;

        return $this->posts->matching($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * @return Post[]
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('postType', 'comment'))
        ;

        return $this->posts->matching($criteria);
    }
```